# Angular Logic in factory or in Controller for webservice return

Tags: angularjs, web-services

Here is my current factory

```
    .factory('Service',function($http,LOOKUP_ENDPOINT){
        'use strict';
        var API = {};

        API.getcode = function(code){
          var args = {
              'code': code,
              'callback': 'JSON_CALLBACK'
            },
            params = ('?callback=' + args.callback);
          return $http.jsonp(LOOKUP_ENDPOINT + params);
        };
  return API;
})
```

And then here is my controller I have something like this

```
APIService.getcode($scope.searchQuery)
  .success(function(data){
    search.result = data;
    $location.path("/result");
    $scope.search = search;
});
```

There is a lot more logic I want to add now for when I get back the return data from my webservice

I.e.

If Return data has result then load certain scope objects & redirect to result screen, if no data returned then return error message to front end etc

Is it normal to have all this in the Controller or Factory ?

Comment: You shall control all routes related stuff on controller. However you can use the boolean in your service and return that boolean variable from service and by verifying that boolean variable you can redirect the pages in controller.

Comment: What about the .success .error logic should that be in controller or factory

Comment: You should ideally handle success and error in your controller. That what mostly angular good practices says.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, when we go by seperation of concerns, You should ideally place your "common" stuff in Services and "specific" stuff in controller.

Considering your problem, i assume that you want to centralize the api calls in Service but the logic inside the controller.

You can do it this way :

```
  .factory('Service',function($http,LOOKUP_ENDPOINT){
        'use strict';
        var API = {};

        API.getcode = function(code, successCallbackFunction, failureCallbackFunction){
          var args = {
              'code': code,
              'callback': 'JSON_CALLBACK'
            },

           var promise = $http.jsonp(LOOKUP_ENDPOINT + params),
           promise.success(function(data, status, header, config) {

             successCallbackFunction(data);

            }),

            promise.error(function(data, status, header, config) {
                failureCallbackFunction(data, status, header, config);
            });
        };
  return API;
})
```

and in your controller :

```
    APIService.getcode($scope.searchQuery, function(data) {
        //function to execute on success
    }, function(data, status, header, config) {
        //function to execute on failure
    });
```

Comment: Ah I have never seen that syntax you have in the controller with two functions, how does it know the first one is the success function and the error is the second one ? I like it a lot

Comment: Ahh, that's upon you @StevieB. The Sequence doesn't matter as such. You just need to decide yourself. Kind of a SOP. and then invoke the functions from the Service. God Grace Javascript, you can treat functions as objects too..

Answer (score 0):

You should do `logical part` in `controller` itself. Basically `factory/service` is useful for `common functionality` for controllers. Means, the same `factory/service` can be used in other controllers.

Answer (score 0):

To my mind good practice is using interceptors [from here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) , and define error handling/spinner on load/other_stuff there. Also you can wrap $http service with your own to make code more flexible via inheritance, but it depends on how big is your project.